# Optimal XAML editing with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, silverlight, xaml, ide, editor

I've recently started developing Silverlight applications in Visual Studio and noticed that the XAML editor there is not optimal. Meaning, I can see the XAML in a text editor with pretty colors, but other than that it doesnt give me much productivity, like C# code, with all the list of methods and parameters in a drop down list and other helpfule views and windows. Is there really not much support in VS2010 for easier editing of XAML files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u can try to use something like [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/)